# Limits are additive, but suprema and infima aren't?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I find it curious that limits have the additive property, but suprema are only subadditive and infima are only superadditive. Since extrema are limits, why is this so?

I was thinking if, for uniformly bounded functions all defined over the same set of finite measure, the supremum over such functions is additive, not just subadditive. Is this true? Are there more general conditions for functions where suprema and infima are additive over?

Comment: Extrema are not limits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a sense in which $\limsup$ is a limit. If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence, then $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sup_{m>n} a_m\right)$$

Now, limits are additive, but that just means that:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n + \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sup_{m>n} a_m + \sup_{m>n} b_m\right)$$

Unfortunately, $$\sup_{m>n} a_m + \sup_{m>n} b_m \neq \sup_{m>n} (a_m+b_m)$$

in general.  We can only say:

$$\sup_{m>n} a_m + \sup_{m>n} b_m \geq \sup_{m>n} (a_m+b_m)$$

Comment: Ah yes, both you and doctorbatmangod have been helpful. To clarify, using only the supremum as an example, I think (correct me if I am wrong) a supremum of the image of a bounded continuous function f is equal to the limit of some strictly increasing sequence sf of points on f. In this sense, wouldn't sup{sf1+sf2}=limit(sf1+sf2)=limit(sf1)+limit(sf2)=sup{sf1}+sup{sf2}?

Comment: No, $\sup$ is the absolute supremum, and has nothing to do with a limit. For example, if $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then $\sup_{m>n} a_m = \frac{1}{m+1}$. It is not a limit of any subsequence.

Comment: But an is not strictly increasing...

Comment: A supremum is related to a limit by the fact that the supremum of any bounded infinite set of points is equal to a limit of some sequence of points on that set. Correct? This is essentially the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: @David only if the supremum is not in the set, or if you allow repeated elements from the set.

Comment: Absolutely. You are correct! However, since curves defined by a function are closed, they must contain all the limit points of all infinite point sets in the curve. My 1st comment has a mistake; I meant the sups to be taken over the functions. However, with that correction, I think my assertion is correct, with the corrections...              a supremum of the image of a bounded continuous function f is equal to the limit of some strictly increasing sequence sf of points on f. In this sense, sup{sf1+sf2}=limit(sf1+sf2)=limit(sf1)+limit(sf2)=sup{sf1}+sup{sf2}

Comment: You need to formalize your language - you are making a hash of terminology. When you start talking about curves, it is not at all clear what that has to do with supremum, sinc curves are in multiple dimensions. The trick to understanding these things is to understand the definitions and only apply them when the definition makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

You're comparing apples to oranges. Limits are taken over sequences, while supremum and infimum are defined for sets. This is where the concepts of $\lim\sup $ and $\lim\inf$ are most useful. But in general you won't have full additivity for supremum limits and infimum limits in sequences in a similar way to how interference in wave patterns can be either destructive or constructive. If you have the sequence:
$$1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,...$$
and the sequence
$$0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,...$$
Then their sum is:
$$1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,...$$

Because the "lows" of one coincide with the "highs" of the other, and if you notice the lim sup and lim inf are not additive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the crux here is that additivity of limits assumes existence of limits, which is a stronger condition than existence of extrema or the lim sup/inf. Therefore we can also make a stronger statement.

Both previous arguments are certainly valid, but only to a certain extent:

It is comparing apples to oranges, if you see both notions defined on the biggest possible structure they make sense on, but there are certainly structures that allow the definition of both notions, e.g. sequences or countably infinite sets.

It is also true that extrema are not limits if you go for the most common definition, but if you allow elements of the set to be chosen multiple times, extrema are limits.

tldr: A lot of the discussion boils down to what exactly we are actually talking about.